# Dropdown menu working until I scroll, then its a mess

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I am creating a site with a shrinking header section "on scroll" and a dropdown menu.

The issue I am having is that when I scroll down the dropdown is not being shown correctly. I tried for hours inspecting the "ul" element containing the dropdown, but I can't understand whats going on because when I inspect the element I see the box there, but its not being show.

I set up a demo of my issue here http://makanudos.com/pico/beg.php

You will see that if you don't scroll, it works, once you scroll, even if you scroll back up its messed.

When I removed the shrink function for the header it all works, so my guess is that the error must be there, but after hours I got no luck.

Any point in the right direction will be more than appreciated!

Comment: your demo relies on your intranet (AJAX goes to an internal IP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent `li` that holds the `ul` which animates, gets an inline style of `overflow: hidden`. That's why you can't see the menu opening, even though it's there.

Comment: Yes, remove that statement from your jQuery code. It's attached to the scroll event.

Comment: Genius!! It looks like the `overflow` is created when I call the `animate` so what I had to do was call something like this after the animate `$('.topnav li').css('overflow-x', 'visible');`

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery sets overflow: hidden before animations, to avoid content overflowing out of the element during the animation. To override this behavior, you can try restoring the css:

```
$(element).animate(...).css('overflow', 'visible');
```